# How to store coordinates of selected portion as a list using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, opencv, computer-vision

I want to store the coordinates of selected rectangular region of interests as a list..So that I can iterate over the coordinates and extract information from similar documents

*Right now I can select rectangular region of interest using mouse ,Then if I press **'Enter'** The marking can be continued. If **'Q'** is pressed, It will print the coordinates of lastly selected region of interests*

This is my code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract



coordinates = [] 
  
# Defining the event listener (callback function)
def shape_selection(event, x, y, flags, param): 
    # making coordinates global
    global coordinates 
  
    # Storing the (x1,y1) coordinates when left mouse button is pressed  
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        coordinates = [(x, y)] 
  
    # Storing the (x2,y2) coordinates when the left mouse button is released and make a rectangle on the selected region
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP: 
        coordinates.append((x, y)) 
  
        # Drawing a rectangle around the region of interest (roi)
        cv2.rectangle(image, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (0,0,255), 2) 
        cv2.imshow("image", image) 
  
  
# load the image, clone it, and setup the mouse callback function 
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ocr template\Sample_Invoice.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image,(1000,1000))
image_copy = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image") 
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", shape_selection) 

f = open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ocr template\data.txt', "a")  
  
# keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed 
while True: 
    # display the image and wait for a keypress 
    cv2.imshow("image", image) 
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
  
    if key==13:
        image_roi = image_copy[coordinates[0][1]:coordinates[1][1], 
                               coordinates[0][0]:coordinates[1][0]] 
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_roi).replace(',', ' ').replace('\f', '')
        
        print(text)
        f.write(text + '\n') 
    if key == ord("c"):
        
        image = image_copy.copy()   
    if key == ord("q"):
        f.close()
        
        break
    
    
  
if len(coordinates) == 2: 
    image_roi = image_copy[coordinates[0][1]:coordinates[1][1], 
                               coordinates[0][0]:coordinates[1][0]] 
    cv2.imshow("Selected Region of Interest - Press any key to proceed", image_roi) 
    cv2.waitKey(0) 

# closing all open windows 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What change should I do to my code in order to store coordinates of selected portion as a list ?

Comment: You have already done the hard part so I am not sure what you are asking? Do you want to put the results in a list for later use or for just this cycle of run?

Comment: I want to store the coordinates selected using rectangle tool that I created for selecting the region of interests ,so that I could extract the same information from similar documents

Comment: Then my answer will work for you. Do I need anything extra which is not in there?

Comment: I am now able to get the coordinates as list by using the named tuple .Thanks a lot brother. One more doubt, I am getting..for example, ```[Rectangle(x1=57, x2=124, y1=187, y2=694)]``` as list while selecting a portion. How to pass this stored coordinates to new document

Comment: I do not know how you call another document to process. But you can pass this Rectangle argument just like any other argument. Can you show the code where you start processing another new document?

Comment: Using for loop I tried to iterate over the coordinates stored and tried to pass them to the image and extract text from it                                                                   ```for file in result_list:
       image_roi = image_copy[file] 
       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_roi).replace(',', ' ').replace('\f', '')
        
       print(text)
       f.write(text + '\n') ```    But I am getting error as ```IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already done the hard part.
Assuming that your coordinates variable has the four corners of the rectangle, you can append them to result_list direclty.

```
result_list.append(coordinates)
```

Or you can make use of namedtuple to make a Rectangle.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Rectangle = namedtuple('Rectangle', 'x1 x2 y1 y2')

rectangle_1 = Rectangle(coordinates[0][1],coordinates[1][1],coordinates[0][0],coordinates[1][0])
result_list.append(rectangle_1)
```

You can access the coordinates like rectangle_1.x1, rectangle_1.x2 etc.

If you want to save this list for later use, you can make use of built-in [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module.

```
>>> 
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99999]
>>> f = open('/tmp/cords', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(a,f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
user@Inspiron:~/Code/$ 
user@Inspiron:~/Code/$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('/tmp/cords', 'rb')
>>> import pickle
>>> a = pickle.load(f)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99999]
>>>
```